# SQL query to get specific string between characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have output column named 'data' from command prompt to list files information like this example :

```
15/07/2020  14:31         1.395 image1.jpeg
```

I need query to get file name, file size, and extension to insert into a table column.

The expected result :

```
file    |   size   |   extension
image1  |   1395   |    jpeg
```

I've come up with this query to get the extension :

```
UPDATE table
SET extension = RIGHT(data, charindex('.', REVERSE(data)) - 1)
```

Can anyone help me how to get the file name and the file size? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not split this data out in the command line with the powershell command?

Comment: To expand (this is overly simplified) something like `Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "$($_.BaseName) | $($_.length) | $($_.Extension)"}`

Comment: Or, better yet, insert the data to your SQL database from Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SPLIT_STRING` to break up the string to individual values and then parse out and identify the values you need using a case statement and finally then pivot the rows to columns so its easy to insert each specific value.

```
select
    date, [file], size
from (
select
    case 
        when value like '%/%/%' then 'date' 
        when ISNUMERIC(value) = 0 and value like '%.%' then 'file'
        when ISNUMERIC(value) = 1  and value like '%.%' then 'size'
        else 'na' end type,value
from (select value from STRING_SPLIT ( '15/07/2020  14:31         1.395 image1.jpeg' , ' ' ) ) d
) src
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for type in ([date], [file], [size])
) as piv
```

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This might work, but will break in many scenarios (different date format, strange issues with `ISNUMERIC` or file names like `123.001`... I'd try to find the items in a position safe way... Btw: `STRING_SPLIT()` is not position safe...

Answer (score 1):

One type and position safe splitting calls JSON (needs v2016+) for the rescue:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='15/07/2020  14:31         1.395 image1.jpeg';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[["',REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@YourString,18,1000)),' ','.'),'.','","'),'"]]')) 
     WITH(Number INT           '$[0]'
         ,Size   INT           '$[1]'
         ,[Name] NVARCHAR(150) '$[2]'
         ,Ext    NVARCHAR(150) '$[3]'
         )A;
```

The idea in short:

- Using `REPLACE(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@YourString,18,1000)),' ','.')` cuts away the leading date and time and the spaces.
- We switch the last remaining blank to a dot  (result: `1.395.image1.jpeg`).
- Now we use some replacements to get a JSON array (result `[["1","395","image1","jpeg"]]`)
- We use double brackets to allwo for a WITH clause, where the array is *within* another array.
- Now we can use the position (zero based) to fetch each item and return it typed and named (implicit pivoting).

Hint: If you are below v2016 you can do the same with XML:

```
SELECT TheXml.value('x[1]','int') AS Number
      ,TheXml.value('x[2]','int') AS Size
      ,TheXml.value('x[3]','nvarchar(150)') AS [Name]
      ,TheXml.value('x[4]','nvarchar(150)') AS Ext
FROM (VALUES(CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@YourString,18,1000)),' ','.'),'.','</x><x>') + '</x>'  AS XML))) A(TheXml)
```